# I want to show booked and available timing on selecting particular date

Tags: php, loops

```
     <table style="border: 1px solid;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid;padding:11px;">Time</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid;padding:11px;">Book</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
        $starttime = $query2['starttime'];  // your start time
        $endtime = $query2['endtime'];  // End time
        $duration = '30';  // split by 30 mins
        echo "Availability Timing :- "; echo $starttime;echo " to " ;echo $endtime;
        echo "<span style='color:red;'>"; echo "<br>Availability Days :- "; echo $query2['days']; echo "</span>";
        //echo "<br>Select Date :- "; echo $_POST['date']; 

       $array_of_time = array ();
       $start_time    = strtotime ($starttime); //change to strtotime
       $end_time      = strtotime ($endtime); //change to strtotime

       //echo $single_time; <?php echo current($array_of_time); echo " - ";echo next($array_of_time); echo '<br>';

      $add_mins  = $duration * 60;
      while ($start_time <= $end_time) // loop between time
     {
    $array_of_time[] = date ("h:i a", $start_time);
    $start_time += $add_mins; // to check endtime
     }
    $arr_ctr=count($array_of_time)-1;

      foreach ($array_of_time as $key => $single_time) { 
        if($arr_ctr>$key){
      ?>  
       <tr>
<td style="border:1px solid;padding:11px;">
<?php   

        $query5=mysql_query("select * from doctorbooking where aday='2016-09-29' and demail='".$query2['email']."'");

        $query6=mysql_fetch_array($query5);

        //echo $query6['atime'];

        //var_dump($query6);


         if (($array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1])==$query6['atime']) 
        {
            echo $array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1] . '<br /><span style="color:red;background-color:#C0C0C0;">Booked</span>';
        } else 
        {
            echo $array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1] . '<br /><span style="color:red;">Available</span>';
        }



?>

</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid;padding:11px;">

        <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $array_of_time[$key].' - '.$array_of_time[$key+1]; ?>" id="A" name="A"></td>
      </tr>
      <?php 
      }
      } 
      ?>

      </tbody>
  </table>
```

The problem is that i want to select atime column from the database by selecting particular mail id and date.I have 4 values of atime in the database but it is selecting only the first one,it is not selecting the others.I have check using //echo $query6['atime']; and I want to disable that radio button also if it is booked.

Comment: you will have to loop through the result `while($query6=mysql_fetch_array($query5)){                                                        // do something                                                                                                            }`

Comment: It is not able to select multiple values from the database.It is showing the first one or the last one.i want that it will show all values on perticular date.@ CodeZilla.

Comment: You need to loop through the results to get all values read the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php Also note the mysql is deprecated in PHP 5.5. You should use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: It is not working .can you help please.@CodeZilla.

Comment: It is showing both available and booked .please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php   


        $array_filter = $array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1];
        $is_booked = false;

        $query5=mysql_query("select atime from doctorbooking where aday='2016-09-29' and demail='".$query2['email']."'");

        //$query6=mysql_fetch_array($query5);




        //echo $query6['atime'];

        //var_dump($query6);

        while( $query6 = mysql_fetch_array($query5) ) {           
if ( $array_filter == $query6['atime'] ) {
  //it force "booked" as soon as 1 is booked
  $is_booked = true;

} else {
 // OR uncomment here to force "available" as soon as 1 is availabe
 //$is_booked = false;

}           
 }

  if ($is_booked) {
  echo $array_filter . '<br /><span style="color:red;background-color:#C0C0C0;">Booked</span>';
  } else {
echo $array_filter . '<br /><span style="color:red;">Available</span>';
 }
        //mysql_data_seek($query5,0);

?>
```

this is the solution of this question.